# docker run open a X window and stay idle

Tags: docker, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I'm connecting to a remote machine (from windows to centos) and try to run a docker container.

[For example](https://hub.docker.com/_/hello-world/), `docker pull hello-world`, X window is comming up 
and nothing append.

`ssh -vvv name@remote`
the same command `docker pull hello-world` gives :

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 4 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 35164
debug2: fd 8 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
```

I wonder how to debug this behavior. I think it may come from ssh configuration but not sure.

Comment: I don't understand what `docker pull hello-world` has to do with X11, and I don't know what needs to be debugged here. What did you type where, and why is there an X window coming up?

Comment: Yes. That's the point. I don't know why this docker command shows a X window too... 

Trying to be clear. I'm connecting from windows to a remote centos with ssh -vvv name@centos. Then I run the docker command above and an empty X11 window pop up. 

I close window and having this output/error in command line : `XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:10.0"
      after 32 requests (30 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
`